# Relationship queries (parent-child)

Tags: soql, relationships

I am new to Salesforce and I am struggling to get my head around the correct SOQL which correctly reference multiple tables.

Some background:

I have a custom field in `Order Product` called `Teacher_c`. This field is related to `Contact` with child relationship name `Order_Products2`.

In the WSDL - For `Contact`:

```
<element name="Order_Products2__r" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>
```

In the WSDL - For `OrderItem`:

```
<element name="Teacher__c" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:ID"/>
<element name="Teacher__r" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ens:Contact"/>
```

I have tried to write SOQL to get all order items and include the teacher name such as:

```
SELECT OrderItem.Id, OrderItem.UnitPrice, OrderItem.Quantity, Teacher_r.name
    FROM OrderItem
```

I know the error is `Teacher_r.name` but I have tried a number of different attempts without luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the error thrown by the above query. It seems like it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to reference the Teacher table through the relationship using the denotion "Teacher__r". I am not sure if this is just a copy and paste error but the relationship that you pasted into your code only has 1 underscore and looked like "Teacher_r" while it should look like "Teacher**__**r". Also in the error message that you mention in the comment to @Nick Cook's answer:

> When I try Teacher_r.name,Contact.Teacher_r.name it get the following error: "Didn't understand relationship 'Contact' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name."

When choosing fields to be returned in the SELECT portion of the SOQL query you do not need to state the name of the object (data table) the fields (columns) live on, you can simply reference them as follows:

```
list<OrderItem> orderItems = [SELECT Id, UnitPrice, Quantity, Teacher__r.Name FROM OrderItem];
```

The above query will bring back a list of order item records with the fields Id, UnitPrice, Quanitity and Teacher__r.Name.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell because you're using the terms 'Order' and 'Product' interchangeably.   By the looks of it, you're doing a query on the OrderItem object, but the Contact lookup is on the Order object.
This means you have three levels of relationship (a grandparent).

try:

```
SELECT Id, UnitPrice, Quantity, Order.Teacher__r.Name FROM OrderItem
```

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the quick response. Your right, I am querying the OrderItem object. The custom field I mentioned earlier created was in the OrderItem object too. The idea is each order has multiple order item, within each order item there can be a teacher assigned to it. The teacher is linked to the contact table. When I try Teacher_r.name,Contact.Teacher_r.name it get the following error "Didn't understand relationship 'Contact' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name."